# Error : Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

Tags: android, searchview, android-debug

hope you'all doing fine. Im working on an android application that uses a searchview to do a search for data from Firebase relatime database medicines info db
the app crash after i open the activity that contains the SearchView, after a debugging i got this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.projetfe, PID: 26491
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projetfe/com.example.projetfe.MedicamentActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.projetfe.MedicamentActivity.onCreate(MedicamentActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(ViewCompat.java:2560)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:300)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.java:271)
            ... 30 more
```

i don't know what i did wrong. so i'm asking for your help.
There is my main medicines class :

```
package com.example.projetfe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MedicamentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    SearchView searchView1;
    myadapter myadapter;
    DatabaseReference ref;
    ArrayList<model> list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.medicaments);

        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("1").child("data");
        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
        searchView1 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (ref != null)
        {
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists())
                    {
                        list = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            list.add(ds.getValue(model.class));
                        }
                        myadapter myadapter = new myadapter(list);
                        recyclerView1.setAdapter(myadapter);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MedicamentActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
         if (searchView1 != null)
         {
             searchView1.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                 @Override
                 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                     return false;
                 }

                 @Override
                 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                     search (s);
                     return true;
                 }
             });
         }
        }
    private void search(String str)
    {
        ArrayList<model> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(model object : list)
        {
            if(object.getNOM_DE_MARQUE().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase()))
            {
                myList.add(object);
            }

        }
        myadapter myadapter = new myadapter(myList);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(myadapter);
    }

}
```

its Layout xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/drugs"
    tools:context=".MedicamentActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E6B0AA">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="txt"
            android:textColor="#E74C3C"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:queryHint="cherchez" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Adapter:

```
package com.example.projetfe;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myadapter.MyViewHolder>
{
    ArrayList<model> list;
    public myadapter(ArrayList<model> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerow,viewGroup,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.nom.setText(list.get(position).getNOM_DE_MARQUE());
        holder.dosage.setText(list.get(position).getDOSAGE());
        holder.forme.setText(list.get(position).getFORME());
        holder.pays.setText(list.get(position).getPAYS_DU_LABORATOIRE_DETENTEUR_DE_LA_DECISION_DENREGISTREMENT());
        holder.remboursement.setText(list.get(position).getREMBOURSEMENT());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView nom, forme, dosage, pays, remboursement;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nametext);
            forme = itemView.findViewById(R.id.formetext);
            dosage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dosagetext);
            pays = itemView.findViewById(R.id.paystext);
            remboursement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rembtext);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **migrate** your project to `androidX`. Check here on [how to migrate to androidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

This will also help

[image]